# Count How Many In Column A are also in Column B

Tags: regex, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to create a formula to count how many cells in a first column are also in a second column. It's 2 lists from the same source of unique id's, fitting 2 different criteria, and I want to count how many fit both criteria. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N(REGEXMATCH(B1:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A1:A)))))
```

[image]